# Как «рекконектить» MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="container" id="container" contenteditable>
  blabla
</div>
```

Функция - `obs_container` следить за изменением container.

Если нажать на кнопку "добавить main" в container добавляется div main.

Мне нужно следить за container пока нет main. но если main есть. то перестать следить за container и начать следить только за main и наоборот, если main-а нет.

Как это можно сделать ? Можно конечно вызывать нужную функцию на кнопке, но хотелось бы в самом observer-е проверять

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/htoLaw2s/)

Comment: Мне просто интересно, а зачем следить за изменениями в DOM? Эти изменения от кого исходят? Может лучше следить за своим кодом? Или так сейчас делается? Это ладно. Но можно ведь следить только за контейнером, за изменением его атрибутов. А при добавлении `main` менять атрибут в контейнере...

Comment: @Leonid, атрибут `contenteditable` говорит, что данные в див будут вводиться пользователем

Comment: @Grundy, `contenteditable` значит, что пользователь может  редактировать данные, я пользовался такой штукой для самодельной админки)) Я про `MutationObserver`, ему, насколько я понял, надо передавать за чем именно следить: за изменением атрибутов, или `childList`. Вот я и предлагаю при изменении структуры `child` менять и какой-нибудь атрибут контейнера и таким образом отслеживать изменения. Если речь о природе изменений в DOM, то в коде ничего такого нет, а `contenteditable` вряд ли позволит пользователю менять структуру элемента, только текстовые данные.

Comment: К тому же для `contenteditable` можно прописать слушателя `'input'`